# HBase Spark connection options [Java]

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, database-connection

I am trying to access HBase from a java Spark application running on YARN, but I need some clues on how to do it. I've already searched online, but I cannot find definitive answers. Here they are:

- The basic one: how do I interact with HBase from Spark? Do I need to set up an HBase connection on each worker (maybe via mapPartition to save some connections), or I can share it from the driver after creation?
- Can HBase table objects instantiated and shipped by the driver to the workers in order to execute Put and Get operations on them?
- (Related to the previous one) Is it a good practice to interact with HBase in Spark using single Put/Get operations? Any alternative?

Thank you for the answers

Comment: Not sure if still relevant to you -- just posted the following which works for Java (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49494483/hbase-spark-connector-connection-to-hbase-established-for-every-scan). Seems to work OK, but my concern is that it seems to not reuse the HBase connection with distributed Scans, as one would expect. In case you try, would be curious what you think of this...

Answer (score 0):

Q1: You could use [Hortonworks Spark HBase Connector](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc) (of the 3 connectors available this supports Spark 2.x)

This will simplify q2 and q3 above.  You will be able to load data from HBase as an RDD and then manipulate it how you like (transform to Dataframe and operate here, or convert to tmp table im-memory and write sql queries on top etc etc)

Follow the setup on the above link, and you can..

To load a table:

```
def catalog = s"""{
        |"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"table1"},
        |"rowkey":"key",
        |"columns":{
          |"col0":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
          |"col1":{"cf":"cf1", "col":"col1", "type":"boolean"},
          |"col2":{"cf":"cf2", "col":"col2", "type":"double"},
          |"col3":{"cf":"cf3", "col":"col3", "type":"float"},
          |"col4":{"cf":"cf4", "col":"col4", "type":"int"},
          |"col5":{"cf":"cf5", "col":"col5", "type":"bigint"},
          |"col6":{"cf":"cf6", "col":"col6", "type":"smallint"},
          |"col7":{"cf":"cf7", "col":"col7", "type":"string"},
          |"col8":{"cf":"cf8", "col":"col8", "type":"tinyint"}
        |}
      |}""".stripMargin

  sqlContext
  .read
  .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog->catalog))
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
  .load()
}
```

To write a table:

```
sc.parallelize(data).toDF.write.options(
  Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5"))
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
  .save()
```

Comment: Thank you @jayfah for the answer. My bad, I did not pointed out the programming language (Java), and the fact that data is highly unstructured, so providing the catalog would not be an easy task. Is it possible to execute single Get and Put using the connector mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both options:

1. set up an HBase connection on each partition (within mapPartition or foreachPartition). If you want one connection per executor you have to implements a kind of singleton connection object/pool within mapPartition/foreachPartition and share it between all tasks executed by that executor (pay attention that some HBase client API are not thread-safe, last finished task has to close the connection and the client buffer could grow quickly).
2. use Spark-Hbase connector (SHC): you can interact with HBase at very raw level (put, get, scan, delete, mutuation, ...) and not only through structured dataframes

Answer (score 0):

"The basic one: how do I interact with HBase from Spark? Do I need to set up an HBase connection on each worker (maybe via mapPartition to save some connections), or I can share it from the driver after creation?"

A: Use the HBase Spark that are presented in HBase documentation here:
https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#spark
It has a object called HBaseContext that manages it for you. If you interested in how it is done, you can see the source code here with some examples as well: https://github.com/apache/hbase-connectors/tree/master/spark/hbase-spark
See this tutorial for more details: https://sparkbyexamples.com/hbase/spark-hbase-connectors-which-one-to-use/#hbase-spark

"Can HBase table objects instantiated and shipped by the driver to the workers in order to execute Put and Get operations on them?"

A: Some of them can. This is exactly what the library above does. They must be/implement seriazable.
You can deep dive in the implementation of the HBaseContext as an example: https://sparkbyexamples.com/hbase/spark-hbase-connectors-which-one-to-use/#hbase-spark
For more about shipping objects to workers, read about broadcasts and accumulators in spark documentation:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#shared-variables

"(Related to the previous one) Is it a good practice to interact with HBase in Spark using single Put/Get operations? Any alternative?"

A: Its works pretty well, depending on your use case. If you need random read/write per key (in a Spark Streaming pipeline, for example) and low level capabilities the way to go is this library. But if you need more structured capabilities (and has structured data), using DataFrames, and scanning all/a big part of the table, you can use other simpler APIs, as the Phoenix connector or the SHC api. See: [hbase-spark for Spark 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171770/hbase-spark-for-spark-2/66682559#66682559) and https://sparkbyexamples.com/hbase/spark-hbase-connectors-which-one-to-use/.

As a reference, I've checked all those possibilities with Java.