# HBase-Spark Connector: connection to HBase established for every scan?

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, google-cloud-bigtable

I am using Cloudera's HBase-Spark connector to do intensive HBase or BigTable scans. It works OK, but looking at Spark's detailed logs, it looks like the code tries to re-establish a connection to HBase with every call to process the results of a `Scan()` which I do via the `JavaHBaseContext.foreachPartition()`.

Am I right to think that this code re-establishes a connection to HBase every time? If so, how can I re-write it to make sure I reuse the already established connection?

Here's the full sample code that produces this behavior:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FilterList;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FirstKeyOnlyFilter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.KeyOnlyFilter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.PageFilter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.PrefixFilter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.JavaHBaseContext;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction;

import scala.Tuple2;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main
{   
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {

        SparkConf sc = new SparkConf().setAppName(Main.class.toString()).setMaster("local");        
        Configuration hBaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        Connection hBaseConn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hBaseConf);

        JavaSparkContext jSPContext = new JavaSparkContext(sc);
        JavaHBaseContext hBaseContext = new JavaHBaseContext(jSPContext, hBaseConf);

        int numTries = 5;
        byte rowKey[] = "ffec939d-bb21-4525-b1ff-f3143faae2".getBytes();
        for(int i = 0; i < numTries; i++)
        {
            Scan s = new Scan(rowKey);
            FilterList fList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
            fList.addFilter(new KeyOnlyFilter());
            fList.addFilter(new FirstKeyOnlyFilter());
            fList.addFilter(new PageFilter(5));
            fList.addFilter(new PrefixFilter(rowKey));
            s.setFilter(fList);
            s.setCaching(5);            

            JavaRDD<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>> scanRDD = hBaseContext
                    .hbaseRDD(hBaseConn.getTable(TableName.valueOf("FFUnits")).getName(), s);   

            hBaseContext.foreachPartition(scanRDD,  new VoidFunction<Tuple2<Iterator<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable,Result>>, Connection>>(){
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                public void call(Tuple2<Iterator<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable,Result>>, Connection> t) throws Exception{
                    while (t._1().hasNext())
                        System.out.println("\tCurrent row: " + new String(t._1().next()._1.get()));
                }});
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the output from Spark Logs. This output repeats 5 times for each 5 iterations of the loop:

```
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x16261d615db0c5f
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x16261d615db0c5f closed
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3). 2044 bytes result sent to driver
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3) in 300 ms on localhost (1/1)
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 3 (foreachPartition at HBaseContext.scala:98) finished in 0.301 s
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 3.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 3 finished: foreachPartition at HBaseContext.scala:98, took 0.311925 s
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_9 stored as values in memory (estimated size 266.5 KB, free 1391.1 KB)
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_9_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 20.7 KB, free 1411.8 KB)
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_9_piece0 in memory on localhost:57171 (size: 20.7 KB, free: 457.8 MB)
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 9 from NewHadoopRDD at NewHBaseRDD.scala:25
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=hconnection-0xc412556 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=hbase-3:2181
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=hbase-3:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.PendingWatcher@6f930e0
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server 144.240.189.35.bc.googleusercontent.com/35.189.240.144:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 144.240.189.35.bc.googleusercontent.com/35.189.240.144:2181, initiating session
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server 144.240.189.35.bc.googleusercontent.com/35.189.240.144:2181, sessionid = 0x16261d615db0c60, negotiated timeout = 90000
18/03/26 15:51:56 INFO util.RegionSizeCalculator: Calculating region sizes for table "FFUnits".
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing master protocol: MasterService
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x16261d615db0c60
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x16261d615db0c60 closed
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: foreachPartition at HBaseContext.scala:98
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 4 (foreachPartition at HBaseContext.scala:98) with 1 output partitions
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 4 (foreachPartition at HBaseContext.scala:98)
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 4 (MapPartitionsRDD[9] at map at HBaseContext.scala:427), which has no missing parents
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_10 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.9 KB, free 1414.7 KB)
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_10_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1719.0 B, free 1416.4 KB)
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_10_piece0 in memory on localhost:57171 (size: 1719.0 B, free: 457.8 MB)
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 10 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 4 (MapPartitionsRDD[9] at map at HBaseContext.scala:427)
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 4.0 with 1 tasks
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4, localhost, partition 0,ANY, 2611 bytes)
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4)
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO spark.NewHBaseRDD: Input split: HBase table split(table name: FFUnits, scan: GiJmZmVjOTM5ZC1iYjIxLTQ1MjUtYjFmZi1mMzE0M2ZhYWUyKqECCilvcmcuYXBhY2hlLmhhZG9v
cC5oYmFzZS5maWx0ZXIuRmlsdGVyTGlzdBLzAQgBEjIKLG9yZy5hcGFjaGUuaGFkb29wLmhiYXNl
LmZpbHRlci5LZXlPbmx5RmlsdGVyEgIIABI1CjFvcmcuYXBhY2hlLmhhZG9vcC5oYmFzZS5maWx0
ZXIuRmlyc3RLZXlPbmx5RmlsdGVyEgASLwopb3JnLmFwYWNoZS5oYWRvb3AuaGJhc2UuZmlsdGVy
LlBhZ2VGaWx0ZXISAggFElMKK29yZy5hcGFjaGUuaGFkb29wLmhiYXNlLmZpbHRlci5QcmVmaXhG
aWx0ZXISJAoiZmZlYzkzOWQtYmIyMS00NTI1LWIxZmYtZjMxNDNmYWFlMjgBQAGIAQU=, start row: ffec939d-bb21-4525-b1ff-f3143faae2, end row: , region location: 144.240.189.35.bc.googleusercontent.com, encoded region name: 2bce3b6bf780755d19fc4b610b17cf11)
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=hconnection-0x46ac4a0 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=hbase-3:2181
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=hbase-3:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.PendingWatcher@5a8a2d2
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server 144.240.189.35.bc.googleusercontent.com/35.189.240.144:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 144.240.189.35.bc.googleusercontent.com/35.189.240.144:2181, initiating session
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server 144.240.189.35.bc.googleusercontent.com/35.189.240.144:2181, sessionid = 0x16261d615db0c61, negotiated timeout = 90000
18/03/26 15:51:57 INFO mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase: Input split length: 4 M bytes.
    Current row: ffec939d-bb21-4525-b1ff-f3143faae246*1*0049424a-5cea-46cb-a6b0-7c50d6465588
    Current row: ffec939d-bb21-4525-b1ff-f3143faae246*1*0082054a-b86a-4263-9753-025c1b0607be
    Current row: ffec939d-bb21-4525-b1ff-f3143faae246*1*00e21835-5dc6-4d82-8b8c-a4dcae4f14cd
    Current row: ffec939d-bb21-4525-b1ff-f3143faae246*1*01129620-a599-4fb7-9e2f-3492df1d06a3
    Current row: ffec939d-bb21-4525-b1ff-f3143faae246*1*035b3450-e523-4df6-a24f-11ebb29050f7
```

My hbse-site.xml file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>hbase-3</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>timeout</name>
    <value>5000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I am using the following versions:

```
Spark v 1.6.2
HBase 1.3.1
Spark-HBase 1.2.0-cdh5.14.0
```

Thanks for any help and advice!

Comment: I think it is quite normal that a new HBase connection is established within each mapPartition/foreachPartition because the RDD is distributed by design and the connection object cannot be serialized between different nodes. Instead, if you want to have only one HBase connection per executor and share it with all tasks executed in that node, you have to implement a kind of singleton connection object/pool within foreachPartition but pay attention about the thread-safe limitations of some HBase client APIs, the buffer size at client level and to close the connection once last task has finished.

Comment: Not sure I agree. In fact, one thing to note here is that this re-connecting happens only for the operation involving hBaseContext.hbaseRDD(), which in this case is needed to perform a parallelized Scan. If you do hBaseContext.foreachPartition() on an RDD, which also passes the Connection object to each Executor, then the Connection seems to be re-used by each executor (at least I'm not seeing the Spark Log entries showing that Connections are being re-istablished each time.

Comment: hBaseContext.foreachPartition()  is not passing the connection object to the executors (TCP connection cannot be serialized) but is broadcasting the HBaseConfiguration to them; it is in charge of the target executor to establish the direct hbase connection with the right RegionServer. Of course this is done once per partition and not for all rows. Could you please try to remove the Hbaseconnection from the JavaRDD? JavaRDD<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>> scanRDD = hBaseContext.hbaseRDD(TableName.valueOf("FFUnits"), s);

Comment: This way it's the same thing. This is how I had it originally, but I added HBaseConnection.getTable(...) just in case to see that maybe this way the existing connection will be reused. Maybe you are right and we are just looking at a log-reporting rather than an actual implementation issue. As said, this only happens with the HBaseRDD that gets built from a Scan by using HBaseContext.hbaseRDD(...). In other functionality of the HBase-Spark package that require constant contact with HBase cluster, multiple re-connections don't get reported. Maybe they actually happen, just dont' get reported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem. The cost of creating a connection can dwarf the actual work you're doing.

In Cloud Bigtable, you can set `google.bigtable.use.cached.data.channel.pool` to `true` in your configuration settings.  That would significantly improve performance.  Cloud Bigtable ultimately uses a single HTTP/2 end point for all of your Cloud Bigtable instances.

I don't know of a similar construct in HBase, but one way to do this would  would suggest creating an implementation of `Connection` that creates a single cached `Connection` under the covers.  You would have to set the `hbase.client.connection.impl` to your new class.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the suggestion! In Bigtable, where/how exactly would I set this setting? Is it just like this? Connection btConn = BigtableConfiguration.connect("PROJECT_ID", "BT_INSTANCE_ID"); 
  btConn.getConfiguration().set("google.bigtable.use.cached.data.channel.pool", "true");

Comment: I tried this with Bigtable, both by using hbase-site.xml (and using that to establish the connection) and by putting it directly into the code like this: btConf.set(BigtableOptionsFactory.BIGTABLE_USE_CACHED_DATA_CHANNEL_POOL, "true"); (also tried .setBoolean(); none of these seems to make any impact -- still tries to connect to the server each time.

Comment: It's ok to have multiple Connection objects; the underlying Netty channel objects matter much more.  Ideally, you would see useCachedDataPool=true in the BigtableOptions printout.  Unfortunately, there's a bug in BigtableOptions.toString() which does not print out that value (will fix in 1.3.1).  You can use this method: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-metrics to see how many connection are active.

I'll see what I can do to improve the usability of this feature further in 1.3.1.

Comment: @VS_FF, if you think that Solomon's answer is correct, you should consider accepting it to confirm that your issue has been solved. Thank you.